# Why UI changes happen when adding a new fragment to Fragment manager instead of replacing it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, fragmentmanager

I am using `CollapsingToolbarLayout` in and Fragments in my activity.

I am using below code in order to add a new fragment to my activity:

```
 FragmentDetails fragmentDetails = FragmentDetails.newInstance();
    new DetailPresenter(fragmentDetails, appRepository, requestedPostId);
    fm.beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentDetails, String.valueOf(requestedPostId))
      .addToBackStack(String.valueOf(requestedPostId))
      .commit();
```

and everything is ok, But I want to use `add` instead of `replace` in my `FragmentManager` like this:

```
 FragmentDetails fragmentDetails = FragmentDetails.newInstance();
    new DetailPresenter(fragmentDetails, appRepository, requestedPostId);
    fm.beginTransaction()
      .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragmentDetails, String.valueOf(requestedPostId))
      .addToBackStack(String.valueOf(requestedPostId))
      .commit();
```

But when I use `add` instead of `replace` my `CollapsingToolbarLayout` jump to out of screen about `5dp`, and my fragment view will be something like this:

[image]

Why does this happen? I searched a lot but found nothing.

**Update:**
I checked this on different devices.
This happens in API 23 and above!
For example in a device with Android 4.4.2, everything is ok.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved this problem after a long time!

This happened to me because of `CoordinatorLayout`. I can't understand why but the problem was about my toolbar layout that took a margin from top of `Appbar` layout.

I put all my code in a `Linearlayout` and it solved my problem!